# Read string from console along with whitespaces

Tags: c++, cin, getline

I want to read a string from cin until the return key is pressed. What's wrong with the following code? The output repeatedly says "Invalid response found, please enter again: " even when i enter single words.. I've updated the code..

```
int readInt() {
    int num;
    while (!(std::cin >> num)) {
        std::cout << "Invalid response found, please enter again: ";
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }

    return num;
}

string readString() {
    string str;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, str) && std::cin.fail()) {
        std::cout << "Invalid response found, please enter again: ";
        std::cin.clear();
        std::cin.ignore();
    }

    return str;
}

DVD_Node* addNewDvd(DVD_Node *head) {
    DVD_Node* temp = new DVD_Node;

    int new_id = getNewID(head);
    temp->id = new_id;

    cout << "\n\n-- Add a new DVD to your collection --";
    cout << "\n\nEnter movie name: ";
    temp->title = readString();

    cout << "\n\nEnter duration in minutes: ";
    temp->duration = readInt();

    cout << "\n\nEnter movie year: ";
    temp->year = readInt();

    cout << "\n\nEnter movie actor 1 name: ";
    temp->actor1 = readString();

    cout << "\n\nEnter movie actor 2 name: ";
    temp->actor2 = readString();

    temp->next = head;

    changes_remaining = 1;
    cout << "\n\nYour DVD Data has been added successfully.";

    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `std::getline(std::cin, str) && std::cin.fail()`?

Comment: What is your definition of "invalid response"? Make sure you understand the problem you're trying to solve before you write code.

Comment: `getline` returns the stream anyway, the fail check is redundant, and you should check for `!std::getline(std::cin, str)`

Comment: Please have a look at the updated code.. when i run it and enter the data i get temp->title = "", correct values for temp->duration, temp->years, temp->actor1 = "" and temp->actor2 = <whatever i entered for actor1> ..

Comment: @remyabel I'm not trying to define "invalid response" I'm just printing it after I check getline() and fail() in the loop condition.. it doesn't work even if i use !getline..

Comment: @Ananth What do you mean? What's the point of your code then? You need to determine what "invalid response" means to you, write the error checking accordingly. `if (!std::getline(std::cin, str))` is enough to determine if there was an error in the stream. Your current code just has an infinite loop for no reason.

Comment: @remyabel yes if is enough to determine if there was an error. But I want to ask the user for the same input again if there is an error. i.e. say there's an error in reading title, i prompt the user to enter it again. Pls suggest something better than a loop for this if possible

Comment: @Ananth Yes, but `invalid response` is orthogonal to there being an error in reading the stream. Your user will not understand what they did wrong. That's why I'm saying, figure out what "invalid response" is.

Comment: `std::getline(std::cin, str) && std::cin.fail()` is schizophrenic. The first half is converted to `true` if the read didn't fail; the second half is `true` if it did fail.

Comment: @T.C. I've changed it to while (!std::getline(std::cin, str) || std::cin.fail())

Answer (score 0):

The below test is not correct if you want to detect error :

```
std::getline(std::cin, str) && std::cin.fail()
```

Indeed, because `getline` return the input, you want to detect null input or errors with :

```
std::getline(std::cin, str) == 0 || std::cin.fail()
```